# Porting a R-CRAN package to renjin using the forecast package as an example

Tags: r, renjin

renjin's approach seems to be great. However compatibility to base R is not 100% and there are lots of very interesting packages out there which do not / only partly work with renjin.

I am fairly new to renjin but really would like to use it. But some important packages like the `forecast` package are missing - or at least the tests do not run in renjin.

To focus this question a little bit more I started to port the forecast package.  You will find the current status https://github.com/geoHeil/forecast However it still contains errors.

- Why does the build crash if I delete the man folder where the R documentation resides in?
- I understand that other referenced packages may cause problems on import but even if they are disabled I still cannot load the namespace file to run my simple example `hamcrest` test-case
- Why does it try to load the package from CRAN? Why is no default package specified?

This is the error message:

```
No default packages specified
Could not load this project's namespace (it may not have one)
org.renjin.eval.EvalException: Could not load package org.renjin.cran:forecast
```

- Is there a better reference as http://docs.renjin.org/en/latest/writing-renjin-extensions.html to show how to move CRAN packages in a renjin compatible format?

Comment: I hope it is less broad now. For me currently I am only interested in the forecast package.

Comment: I added my current github status and improved the questions.

Comment: A lot more packages are supported now http://packages.renjin.org/package